# jQuery Mobile Collapsible div too wide

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue with a jQuery Mobile collapsible div not shrinking any narrower when the page is reduced in width (i.e. as seen on a mobile device). I have it so every other element on the page scales appropriately (width), but the collapsible divs are over-stretching their bounds and I can't get them smaller (wider than the page width).

Cutting off the header label for the collapsible IS ok, I just dont know how. I feel this might be more of a conceptual question, but I post some of the code just for reference:

```
<table id="DataTable" style="width:100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="row" class="Collapsible" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="c" style="margin:0">
        <h3>Example header label (Can be covered)</h3>
        <p>Contents of the div on expand</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the css definition for `.ui-btn-inner`: `white-space: nowrap;`.
Try overwriting it with:

```
.ui-btn-inner {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/p8g7F/).

=== UPDATE ===

You can add following css to change the collapsible `div` (and `h3`) to inline elements:

```
.Collapsible, .Collapsible h3 {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Also see [my updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/p8g7F/2/).

Comment: .ui-btn-inner {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
Works very well! Thank you. Only small thing now is when the div is expanded it goes back to being extra wide, but I'm gonna play around with it and see if its just that style needing to be applied somewhere. I'll post back if I find something. Thank you again!

Comment: Nevermind, the issue was four buttons in the expanded content (the four buttons were forcing it to be so big), and its actually not an issue now that we decided to only support a larger minimum width.